# How to get last parent node with ancestors xpath in html agility pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

How to get last parent node with ancestors XPath in HTML document in HTML Agility Pack (HAP)? For example, I have one HTML document please check below:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>
               <a>
                  <h3>
                  </h3>
               </a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to get the last parent node and their ancestors path in HAP.
For example, the XPath of the above HTML document is

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/a/h3
```

Expect xpath will be

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]
```

Note that I need to get the expected Xpath dynamically - not as a manually hardcode value. For example, based on the last element I need to get the parent with ancestors path.

Comment: Last parent node of WHAT? Why division node expected to be *the last parent node*? Why not an anchor node? It is an actual parent of header

Comment: @Andersson,last parent node it means ..last element(h3) of parent node .Here last element is h3 i want his first parent  and previous full node path like expected  Xpath as i mentioned above post.

Comment: @wp78de,Thank you so much its working as i expected......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, Html-Agility-Pack comes with an XPath property and some methods to get exactly what you want.

So, somehow select a HtmlNode, move to the parent node and retrieve the ancestors XPath (from the first/last via Linq) like this:

```
htmlNode.ParentNode.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault().XPath
```

to get the first ancestor, the last works like this

```
htmlNode.ParentNode.Ancestors().LastOrDefault().XPath
```

or iterate over the Ancestors.